# How can I have an arbitrary function run when certain conditions are met?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm looking to create a library that allows users to create console-options with text (what the user will see in the console) and either a function or another set of Options tied to selecting any given Option.)

What I'm working towards right now are having two core classes to handle this functionality:

OptionView (set of Options for that particular scenario)

Option (a particular option which shows the displayed text and contains the function that will be run when selected, or the new OptionView that will be displayed (for nested selections))

Example usage would be something like this:

```cs
OptionView mainView = new OptionView();
mainView.AddOption("Option That Results in Another View", OptionView.CreateView(someTextFile)); // returns a new OptionView based off of a predefined set of options in a file.

// or

mainView.AddOption("Leaf Option", FunctionToRunWithUnknownArguments);
```

And this could all be done from setup files, to avoid having to manually create the views, if desired.

The final part would be to execute/display the OptionView:

```cs
mainView.Execute();
```

and at that point the options would be enumerated and the user can type in the associated number to select any options.

If I was to add both of those options to `mainView`, then call `mainView.Execute();`

the following would appear:

```
1. Option That Results in Another View
2. Leaf Option
```

and the user could type '1' or '2' to either have another view be displayed, or to have some designated function be run, respectively.

So the reason I need the functions being passed into to not be of any particular signature is so that this system can be used without restriction in various applications.

I suppose one route would be to make Option generic and have the function that is passed in parameterized dependent on however the user extends the Option class? But the limitations on that would to have to allow an arbitrary amount of parameters for the generic Option. I'm honestly not even sure this is possible as I've never tried it.

Any ideas on what a decent way on implementing this could be? Or if it's even possible?

Comment: If you pass an arbitrary function with any signature, how would you expect the calling code to be able to execute it?

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase. I want to be able to pass in whatever function, but it is known at the time of creating the option. For example: new Option("Text", AddProduct("413rs", 100) ); OR new Option("Text", CreateOrder(someArgumentsDifferentFromTheFirstOption) );

It's also possible I'm misunderstanding the question you're giving me. Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: Could use Actions with all the parameters needed as part of the closure, would simplify invocation and parameter passing.

Comment: Scotty, could you perhaps provide an example? :)